Why does Google Sheets show conflicting results in the mobile App vs PC browser when it comes to spilled arrays? Two examples provided

I have two examples showing spilled arrays behaving differently in the mobile App vs on the PC. One example results in different values being displayed, while the other results in different functionality being allowed.
Example 1: Intersecting sequence arrays. The mobile App appears to still be allowing spilled arrays to intersect with each other, with the most recent array overwriting the other. While on the PC, the horizontal sequence takes priority, blocking the vertical sequence and causing it to display a #REF! error.
Example 2: Locking a checkbox using a spilled array. The PC allows you to attempt to spill an array onto a checkbox, resulting in a #REF! error, but also freezing the checkbox into its current state of TRUE/FALSE. However, on the mobile App, the spilled array, which still displays a #REF! error, does not prevent the other checkbox from being used as normal.
Here is a the spreadsheet with both examples.
Two examples of spilled arrays behaving differently in the App vs PC
I've had others confirm that they would observe the same behavior in the App vs the PC browser. Is there a preferred way to identify problems such as this to the Google Sheets developers?

The preferred way is to send feedback in app. You can also create an issue in the issuetracker, if relevant.

In the web version of Sheets: Help > Help Sheets improve or Help > Report a Problem.

You may opt to file a feature request using this link.

This isn't an API or Apps Script issue, so I don't think the issue tracker would be the right place to file a report.

Thank you. I reported this as a problem through the help menu.

Your feedback will go directly to the development team. They are not able to respond to these requests directly, but do take them into account. Issues are prioritized by the number of requests.
